# WordPress filter - add separate rel to multiple galleries in one post

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, fancybox, gallery

I have a WordPress post/page that I want to have multiple galleries in. I am using [this WordPress plugin](http://konstruktors.com/projects/wordpress-plugins/multiple-galleries/) to manage the multiple galleries (it basically includes the selected image id in each gallery shortcode instance). This produces the following html with different IDs for the separate galleries:

```
<div id="gallery-1">
   <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
     <a href="big-image.jpg"><img src="small-img.jpg" /></a>
    </dt>
   </dl>
   <dl> ...another image... </dl>
</div>
<div id="gallery-2">
   <dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="gallery-icon">
     <a href="big-image.jpg"><img src="small-img.jpg" /></a>
    </dt>
   </dl>
   <dl> ...another image... </dl>
</div>
...and so on
```

In addition I have a filter that adds a `rel` attribute to each anchor that links to an image:

```
function slicetheme_attachment_filter($attachment_link)
{   
    global $post;
    $pattern = "/<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
    $replacement = '<a$1rel="fancybox[%LIGHTID%]" href=$2$3.$4$5  $6>$7</a>';
    $attachment_link= preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $attachment_link);
    $attachment_link = str_replace("%LIGHTID%", $post->ID, $attachment_link);
    return $attachment_link;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'slicetheme_attachment_filter');
```

I modified it so I get a gallery from each post/page by adding a `rel` with the post ID. So for post with `ID=553` I have:

```
<a rel="fancybox[553]" href="big-image.jpg"><img src="small-img.jpg" /></a>
```

But this is not what I want. I want each gallery to have a different rel attribute to its anchors. Something like:

```
<div id="gallery-1">
     <dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a rel="fancybox-gallery-1" href="big-image.jpg"><img src="small-img.jpg" /></a>
      </dt>
     </dl>
     <dl> ...another image... </dl>
 </div>
 <div id="gallery-2">
     <dl class="gallery-item">
      <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a rel="fancybox-gallery-2" href="big-image.jpg"><img src="small-img.jpg" /></a>
      </dt>
     </dl>
     <dl> ...another image... </dl>
 </div>
```

I tried to match the whole thing but I guess I'm not good at it...

```
$pattern = "/<div(.*?)id=('|\")gallery-(.*?)('|\")(.*?)<a(.*?)href=('|\")([^>]*).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/i";
$replacement = '<div$1id=$2gallery-$3$4$5<a$6rel="fancybox-gallery-$3" href=$7$8.$9$10  $11>$12</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy functions `gallery_shortcode()`, then add `apply_filter('gallery_shortcode', 'your_gallery_shortcode_copy')` and in you `your_gallery_shortcode_copy()` function and replace `wp_get_attachment_link()` with your own code where gallery id is static property `$instance`.